# How to Make a Silverlight Clip Data Resize before being Applied as a Clip

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I want the clip path to automatically stretch to the width and height of a parent element.

Step 1

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White" Width="600" Height="600">
    <Image Source="/Desert.jpg" Stretch="Fill"/>        
</Grid>
```

[image: Image Stretches to 600x600]

I than drew a heart shape which is bigger than 600x600

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White" Width="600" Height="600">
    <Image Source="/Desert.jpg" Stretch="Fill"/>        
    <Path Fill="White" Data="M354.67316,103.43996 C347.2861,87.291679 314.84012,29.107136 238.84006,6.6071892 C238.84006,6.6071873 221.0666,0.84548211 194.3698,0.55251884 C178.35172,0.37673342 159.12123,2.1696978 138.58997,8.3571806 C83.839897,24.857141 53.460484,64.142944 45.710514,73.392952 C46.114811,72.734512 22.339975,106.35702 16.710522,129.89299 C16.710522,129.89299 5.8399811,163.85704 2.3399515,201.35704 C-0.48841667,232.44208 0.086564839,263.52527 3.0899818,294.60712 C7.9390402,321.28616 14.078016,345.58807 20.506205,369.35715 C20.506205,369.35715 35.150459,408.43985 42.839603,422.35718 C45.804752,434.26614 72.256622,476.54443 90.59005,496.54446 C96.256668,503.29446 140.23531,550.68713 177.56865,580.35413 C205.90199,603.85406 250.19028,642.08411 362.10699,691.58392 C362.10699,691.58392 362.48297,691.56604 362.48297,691.56604 C474.3996,642.06622 518.73267,603.81635 547.06598,580.31641 C584.39935,550.64935 628.14935,503.25381 633.81598,496.50381 C652.14935,476.50375 678.60126,434.22546 681.56635,422.31653 C689.25555,408.39914 703.89978,369.31644 703.89978,369.31644 C710.32794,345.54733 716.46692,321.24539 721.31592,294.56635 C724.31934,263.48447 724.89435,232.40128 722.06598,201.31622 C718.56592,163.81618 707.6955,129.85211 707.6955,129.85211 C702.06598,106.31613 678.2912,72.693611 678.6955,73.352051 C670.9455,64.102036 640.56616,24.816208 585.8161,8.3162394 C565.28485,2.1287501 546.05432,0.33578444 530.03632,0.51156342 C503.33951,0.80453354 485.56607,6.5662427 485.56607,6.5662479 C409.56607,29.066204 375.85822,86.731186 369.73306,103.39907 C367.48129,109.5267 364.90286,111.34041 362.5423,111.18388 C362.5423,111.18388 359.19095,113.31599 354.67316,103.43996 z" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" />
</Grid>
```

[image]

In order to fit the heart shape to be 600x600 i just add the fill setting

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White" Width="600" Height="600">
    <Image Source="/Desert.jpg" Stretch="Fill"/>        
    <Path Fill="White" Stretch="Fill" Data="M354.67316,103.43996 C347.2861,87.291679 314.84012,29.107136 238.84006,6.6071892 C238.84006,6.6071873 221.0666,0.84548211 194.3698,0.55251884 C178.35172,0.37673342 159.12123,2.1696978 138.58997,8.3571806 C83.839897,24.857141 53.460484,64.142944 45.710514,73.392952 C46.114811,72.734512 22.339975,106.35702 16.710522,129.89299 C16.710522,129.89299 5.8399811,163.85704 2.3399515,201.35704 C-0.48841667,232.44208 0.086564839,263.52527 3.0899818,294.60712 C7.9390402,321.28616 14.078016,345.58807 20.506205,369.35715 C20.506205,369.35715 35.150459,408.43985 42.839603,422.35718 C45.804752,434.26614 72.256622,476.54443 90.59005,496.54446 C96.256668,503.29446 140.23531,550.68713 177.56865,580.35413 C205.90199,603.85406 250.19028,642.08411 362.10699,691.58392 C362.10699,691.58392 362.48297,691.56604 362.48297,691.56604 C474.3996,642.06622 518.73267,603.81635 547.06598,580.31641 C584.39935,550.64935 628.14935,503.25381 633.81598,496.50381 C652.14935,476.50375 678.60126,434.22546 681.56635,422.31653 C689.25555,408.39914 703.89978,369.31644 703.89978,369.31644 C710.32794,345.54733 716.46692,321.24539 721.31592,294.56635 C724.31934,263.48447 724.89435,232.40128 722.06598,201.31622 C718.56592,163.81618 707.6955,129.85211 707.6955,129.85211 C702.06598,106.31613 678.2912,72.693611 678.6955,73.352051 C670.9455,64.102036 640.56616,24.816208 585.8161,8.3162394 C565.28485,2.1287501 546.05432,0.33578444 530.03632,0.51156342 C503.33951,0.80453354 485.56607,6.5662427 485.56607,6.5662479 C409.56607,29.066204 375.85822,86.731186 369.73306,103.39907 C367.48129,109.5267 364.90286,111.34041 362.5423,111.18388 C362.5423,111.18388 359.19095,113.31599 354.67316,103.43996 z" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" />
</Grid>
```

[image]

I now want to use this path to clip the image. I can only copy the data property into the clip path.

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White" Width="600" Height="600">
    <Image Source="/Desert.jpg" Stretch="Fill" Clip="M354.67316,103.43996 C347.2861,87.291679 314.84012,29.107136 238.84006,6.6071892 C238.84006,6.6071873 221.0666,0.84548211 194.3698,0.55251884 C178.35172,0.37673342 159.12123,2.1696978 138.58997,8.3571806 C83.839897,24.857141 53.460484,64.142944 45.710514,73.392952 C46.114811,72.734512 22.339975,106.35702 16.710522,129.89299 C16.710522,129.89299 5.8399811,163.85704 2.3399515,201.35704 C-0.48841667,232.44208 0.086564839,263.52527 3.0899818,294.60712 C7.9390402,321.28616 14.078016,345.58807 20.506205,369.35715 C20.506205,369.35715 35.150459,408.43985 42.839603,422.35718 C45.804752,434.26614 72.256622,476.54443 90.59005,496.54446 C96.256668,503.29446 140.23531,550.68713 177.56865,580.35413 C205.90199,603.85406 250.19028,642.08411 362.10699,691.58392 C362.10699,691.58392 362.48297,691.56604 362.48297,691.56604 C474.3996,642.06622 518.73267,603.81635 547.06598,580.31641 C584.39935,550.64935 628.14935,503.25381 633.81598,496.50381 C652.14935,476.50375 678.60126,434.22546 681.56635,422.31653 C689.25555,408.39914 703.89978,369.31644 703.89978,369.31644 C710.32794,345.54733 716.46692,321.24539 721.31592,294.56635 C724.31934,263.48447 724.89435,232.40128 722.06598,201.31622 C718.56592,163.81618 707.6955,129.85211 707.6955,129.85211 C702.06598,106.31613 678.2912,72.693611 678.6955,73.352051 C670.9455,64.102036 640.56616,24.816208 585.8161,8.3162394 C565.28485,2.1287501 546.05432,0.33578444 530.03632,0.51156342 C503.33951,0.80453354 485.56607,6.5662427 485.56607,6.5662479 C409.56607,29.066204 375.85822,86.731186 369.73306,103.39907 C367.48129,109.5267 364.90286,111.34041 362.5423,111.18388 C362.5423,111.18388 359.19095,113.31599 354.67316,103.43996 z"/>       
</Grid>
```

[image]

So my question is. How do i use Path data for a given shape, and resize its bounding box before its being applied as a clip. Or how do i clip an image to path data after its resized.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is non-trivial.  To adjust a clipping path so it is either initially sized to or resized along with an element, you have to resort to code.  The [ClippingBehavior](http://expressionblend.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/71144#1487727) from the [Blend Samples on codeplex](http://expressionblend.codeplex.com/) is a good illustration of this technique.  By applying a behavior to a UIElement, you get a clipping path in the form of a rounded rectangle.  This clipping path resizes as the associated UIElement resizes.

Comment: Even the ClippingBehavior code actually recreates the path data to fit the new size. If we are talking about a complex shape its going to be next to impossible to know how to resize each node in the shape. My question is how can i just stretch or shrink the whole path shape to fit a certain size just like when i set Stretch=Fill to a Path element.

Comment: The short answer is you must recreate the geometry each time. A Path is actually a UIElement that renders a Geometry (which is composed of lines, arcs, etc).  To perform clipping, you use Geometry objects -- not Path objects.  You *might* be able to catch a resize event on your image, compute the size difference between old and new values, and then create a ScaleTransform with that value which is then applied to your geometry object.  Looking at the docs this looks possible, but I haven't tried it.  I expect you'll get distortions from the scaling, but they may be acceptable in you scenario.

Answer (score 0):

The way I would do it would be to use shaders, because they are lot faster. If you haven't messed with WPF/Silverlight shaders at all you'll have to download the Shaders and the Build Task. [WPF/Silverlight Shader examples](http://wpffx.codeplex.com/) and [Shader Effect Build Task](http://wpf.codeplex.com/releases/view/14962#DownloadId=40167)

I would show you how to do it but it would take me about an hour or so and if you wanted to take this route I can gladly help you.

#### Procedure

1. Install Shader Effect Build Task
2. Look as example project
3. Create a Clip Shader with the parameters

   1. Image
   2. Clips Path as Image Brush
   3. Clip color
4. Then in the shader overlay the Image and the Path Image Brush.
5. Remove the pixels that arent overlayed
6. Set the original Image Efeect to the Clip shader you created

#### CODE

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White" Width="600" Height="600">
    <Image Source="/Desert.jpg" Stretch="Fill">
        <Image.Effect>
            <effects:ClipShader ClipPath="{Binding ElementName="CLIPPATH"}" ClipColor="{Binding ElementName="CLIPPATH",Path="Fill"}"/>
        <Image.Effect>
    </Image>
</Grid>
```

effects: is your XAML reference to the shader library your created.

The good part about this is that as long as the effect is applied it will be updated REALLY fast when the shape moves/resizes/etc.